# Shadows form hdri are harsh and noisy

Tags: materials, node-editor, lighting

[image]Can anyone help me light this indoor scene? The shadows are so harsh or the noise is so much in every render. Can't get it to look good at all. 
 I am just using an hdri and the oversized light bulb shown.
[image]

Comment: For the noise the only real solution is more samples: [how to avoid noisy renders in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles). As for the harshness of the shadows see: [soften shadows projected bh HDRi](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89944/soften-shadows-projected-by-hdri/91780#91780)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [soften shadows projected by HDRi](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89944/soften-shadows-projected-by-hdri/91780#91780)

Comment: Try also changing the values for Multiple Importance Sampling in the world: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8152/what-is-multiple-importance-sample-option